# Process a file in Google Cloud storage

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have some very large files (100GB) in GCS that need to be processed to remove invalid characters.
Downloading them and processing them and uploading them again takes forever.
Does anyone know if it is possible to process them in the Google Cloud Platform eliminating the need for download/upload ?

I am familiar with Python and Cloud functions if those are an option.

Comment: Google Cloud Storage supports "in cloud" object copy. `gsutil` supports this ability. 1) Copy the object to a new object with the corrected name. 2) Delete the original object. You can use the REST API, the SDKs, etc. as well.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.To clarify it is not the name of the file that needs correcting it is the data itself.

Comment: Cloud Storage does not offer compute features. That means you must download/upload.

Comment: To avoid downloading the file *locally* to process it (if you have a bad internet connection), you could always start a Compute Engine VM, download the file on it, process it on this VM with a Python script, and upload the fixed file. It will be quicker, depending on the machine type, but you still need to download/upload it like John Hanley said.

Comment: @norbjd - post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John Hanley said in the comments section, there is no compute features on Cloud Storage, so to process it you **need** to download it.

Once that said, instead of downloading the huge file locally to process it, you can start a Compute Engine VM, download that file, process it with a Python script (since you have stated that you're familiar with Python), and updated the processed file.

It will be probably quicker to download the file on a Compute Engine VM (it depends on the machine type though) than downloading the file on your computer.

Also, for faster downloads of huge files, you can use some `gsutil` options :

```
gsutil \
    -o 'GSUtil:parallel_thread_count=1' \
    -o 'GSUtil:sliced_object_download_max_components=16' \
    cp gs://my-bucket/my-huge-file .
```

And for faster uploads of huge files, you can use parallel composite uploads :

```
gsutil \
    -o 'GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M' \
    cp my-huge-file gs://my-bucket
```